# Display content from "About Us" page on the Home Page

Tags: loop

I have a page called "About Us" with some static content. I want to display that static content on the home page. Would I need to do a custom query that returns the about page, or is there a better way?

```
$about_page = new WP_Query('p=7'); // is this basically it?
```

Is there a better way to do this? A more dynamic way that would allow me to distribute this theme to others who don't have a specific ID for an About page.

EDIT:

Found [this page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) on the Codex. It recommends using the get_page function.

Comment: There are *so* many ways to implement this. The best approach is entirely dependent on your specific use-case. **Question**: are you displaying the "About Us" page, or merely pulling its content into your site front page?

Comment: Pulling. here's the site: http://adultdatinghistory.com/ Left hand side, the section called "welcome to {site name}" is pulled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using WP_Query, then assign that page a custom meta key 'home_content' with a value as 1. Then use [WP_Query's custom field parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) to loop over it. If you can restrict the title as 'About' everywhere, use [get_page_by_title](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_title), and if you can restrict the slug as 'about', use [get_page_by_path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_by_path). These methods will work dynamically.